# Do data type ranges matter as a memory-saving measure anymore?

Tags: c++, memory, types, range

I was always taught to use the appropriate data type depending on the specific needs of the class/method/function/member/variable/what-have-you. That said, does it even matter anymore?

Hypothetically, if I have a class that has a data member that will never be negative and will never be more than the maximum value of `unsigned char`, does storing it as an `unsigned char` (1 byte) versus an `int` (4 bytes) even matter anymore due to implicit type promotion/demotion, internal representation, register size and the often quoted "CPUs are more efficient when working with `int`"?

Example:

```
class Foo {
    public:
        Foo() : _status(0) { /* DO NOTHING */ }
        void AddTo(unsigned char value) {
            if(std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max() - _stat < value) {
                value = std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max() - _status;
            }
            _status += value;
        }

        void Increment() {
            if(_status == std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max()) return;
            ++_status;
        }
    private:
        unsigned char _status;
};
```

Comment: They're not just a memory saving measure. They automatically enforce their own ranges. You can do that in code but it wastes even more memory, as well as time.

Comment: A gigabyte of memory can store a billion `unsigned char`s.  It cannot store a billion `int`s.  This has not changed recently.

Comment: Consider using a library which will handle the `numeric_limits` goo for you, such as [SafeInt](http://safeint.codeplex.com/).

Comment: @EJP: The way in which they "enforce their own ranges", is hardly very useful. It just prevents you from being able to check for values which are out of range.

Comment: "If it can't be negative use unsigned" is a very poor idea. Gee, let's use a type that shows a dangerous discontinuity around zero, just to show how confident we are in the correctness of the code.

Comment: Discontinuity around zero?  Every integral data type has min and max values.  The odds that the use you put them to naturally matches any of them is incredibly low.  Even if they did you still have to check your bounds yourself.  Unless there is a very good reason to used unsigned I'm against it simply because it's a pain to type unsigned.  It's not that much fun to read when it's pointless either.

Comment: @CandiedOrange: I think the "around zero" refers to the fact that most common integer values are clustered around zero. E.g. CPython caching of integer object relies on this. And for that reason the implicit conversions of modern C and C++ get dangerous with unsigned types, promoting any signed integer nearby to unsigned and wrapping the value around 2\^n. Which is the reasons for many compilers' warning about signed/unsigned comparison. And which is just another datum supporting your view. ;-)

Comment: @Kaz: I've clarified the wording. "Can't be negative" can be interpreted as "must never be negative" or "will never be negative". In the case of "Must never be negative" I certainly would not use an unsigned value because I can't check the validity of the input without converting to a signed or larger type first. For "will never be negative" cases, see the example provided in the question.

Answer (score 3):

A main effect of generally using "right-sized" types is that you and others waste a lot of time on it.

If you have a zillion values stored, e.g. a very large picture, or if you absolutely need a 64-bit range, say, then sure, in such cases it makes sense to right-size.

But using right-sizing as a general guideline produces no significant gain and much pain.

Authority argument: Bjarne Stroustrup, who created the language, generally just uses a few types, e.g. `int` for integers.

Answer (score 1):

"Premature optimization is the root of all evil" Donald Knuth.

Is this one data member's size going to significantly impact the size of the class?  Are you serializing the class?  Is the serialization representation seeing any reduction?  Are you making the code harder to read worrying about this when your boss doesn't care?

Y2K, IPv4 32bit addresses, ASCII, yes the future will look back at your code and laugh.  Remember moores law, write something that works, and expect that something will be wrong.  Until it is you'll never know what.  Write testable, maintainable, and refactorable code and it might just stay in production long enough for someone to care.

Comment: Usual incomplete quote from Knuth. You haven't even quoted the entire sentence. I suggest you look it up and see what he really said, and what he was talking about when he said it. It certainly wasn't data type sizes.

Comment: Oh really?  Well how about this then:  "Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%."  Time and space are trade off's in computer science so, yeah he was. :P

Comment: The question isn't about speed, and the quotation is. Well done for looking it up though. It doesn't make sense to consider choosing correct data types to be 'premature', as you have to do it first. Similarly choosing the correct algorithm isn't 'premature' for the same reason, and algorithms are DEK's life work.

Comment: The question is about if he should care.  My answer is about how to judge if he should care.  Time or space the problem he's up against is the same.  It's called the law of diminishing returns.  If you aren't in that 3% you are wasting something much more expensive than CPU time or memory space.  You are wasting development time.

Answer (score 0):

For most use cases when targeting PCs and servers, you're not going to need to worry about using `char`s vs using `int`s to hold numeric values. Just use an `int` or, if you need a larger range, a `long`.

However, if you're targeting a [platform with 16 *bytes* of RAM which has less than 1 KB to store your program](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?product=PIC10F220), you may need to carefully consider whether that loop counter really has to take up more than 1 byte.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's a particular reason for choosing some other variable type, just stick with `int`. A large part of modern programming is managing complexity and there's no reason to start sprinkling your code with a whole variety of types if it doesn't actually help anything. Sure, if you have 5,000 copies of a particular class or working on a system with a tightly constrained memory footprint then it might be important. But on a multigigabyte system this isn't generally going to be a concern. In that case it's more about writing something understandable and maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

You are hitting one of the problems of C-style languages. They deprive the ability to do range checking that you can do in other languages. If your value should be within a specific range, the ability to say a type can be, say,  1..64 is a big help for error tracking. I have found so many bugs in C/C++ code by converting it to pascal or ada.

I like to use typedefs for documentation purposes in the situation you describe--

COLORCOMPONENT
DEGREES
RADIANS

--for documentation purposes. Even if the compiler does not do the checking for me, I can usually spot when I am using degrees when I should be using radians.